# Generate Beta distributed random variables on GCC and MS C++17

Tags: c++, random, c++17

The below code gives me a beta distributed random variable in MSVC c++17:

```
std::mt19937 gen;
std::_Beta_distribution<float> beta(0.5, 0.5);
std::cout << beta(gen) << std::endl;
```

Unfortunately, the same code will not compile on GCC9.3.0. I need code, preferably a single approach that works across both platforms but I will do for separate approaches, to generate a Beta distributed random variable, without using Boost. How to approach this? Is std::_Beta_distribution hidden somewhere else for GCC? Or do I need to write my own code?

Comment: The naming style (`std::_Foo_bar` instead of `std::foo_bar`) hints at it being non-standard. Here's [a list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) of available distributions.

Comment: Using Boost, maybe? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181403/generate-random-number-based-on-beta-distribution-using-boost

Comment: @HolyBlackCat did not know that, and I had been looking for which namespace to add. (Often things in MSVC are in std:: without adding include, but for GCC I need to include.)  I saw the boost option, but would like to avoid that dependency. It seems I will need to bite the bullet and implement something like this: https://gist.github.com/sftrabbit/5068941

Comment: You could just leverage the C++-standard Gamma distribution, and use the [common mathematical trick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution#Computational_methods) to generate a single beta variate from two Gamma variates. See also the accepted answer for [SO-q10358064](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10358064/random-numbers-from-beta-distribution-c).

Comment: Thanks, I think HolyBlackCat's comment basically answered my question. I went with an approach similar to the one in the link you gave.