# unrecognized command line option ‘-framework’

Tags: c, opengl

I am trying to compile the minimalist C opengl code in https://github.com/fogleman/HelloGL on my Ubuntu 18.04 system, but I get the following error:

```
gcc -c -o build/matrix.o -std=c99 -O3 src/matrix.c    
gcc -o main build/shader.o build/main.o build/util.o build/matrix.o  -lglew -lglfw3 -framework Cocoa 
-framework OpenGL -framework IOKit -framework CoreVideo -lm    
gcc: error: Cocoa: No such file or directory    
gcc: error: OpenGL: No such file or directory    
gcc: error: IOKit: No such file or directory    
gcc: error: CoreVideo: No such file or directory    
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-framework’    
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-framework’    
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-framework’   
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-framework’    
Makefile:24: recipe for target 'main' failed
```

I do realize the reason for this is the following line in the MakeFIle, which is made for OSX (presumably):

```
LIBS = -lglew -lglfw3 -framework Cocoa -framework OpenGL -framework IOKit -framework CoreVideo
```

Is there a way of adapting this line to make it work on a **GNU/Linux** system?
Or does it need to have to be linked to the Cocoa framework?

Comment: Take off all the framework options and see if that works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I downloaded this example project and tinkered with it myself.  It does not appear to contain any OSX-specific code; it's just that its Makefile was written for OSX only.

First make sure you have have the `libglfw3-dev` and `libglew-dev` packages installed.  Installing these from the Ubuntu package manager should automatically pull in all the other libraries that are required.

Next, change the `LIBS` line of the Makefile to read

```
LIBS = -lGLEW -lglfw -lGL -lm
```

For no apparent reason, the library called `libglew` on OSX is called `libGLEW` on (Debian-style) Linux, and the library called `libglfw3` on OSX is called `libglfw` on Linux.  `-lGL` is the Linux equivalent of `-framework OpenGL`, and `-lm` brings in the math library (needed for one call to `sqrt`), which is separate from the core C library on Linux but not on OSX, if I remember correctly.

You may also need to adjust the FLAGS line.  This setting worked for me:

```
FLAGS = -g -O2 -std=gnu99 -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic
```

The important change here is `-std=gnu99` instead of `-std=c99`.  The stricter c99 mode is troublesome; it disables extensions that people don't realize *are* extensions, like `math.h` defining the constant `M_PI`, which this program wants.  (It also has a nasty habit of breaking network-related system headers, for reasons which are too complicated to get into here.  Fortunately, this program doesn't use the network.)

I also added `-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic`, added `-g`, and changed `-O3` to `-O2`.  These are all things I do habitually to every C program I tinker with.  The first two *can* reveal problems and they almost never hurt; in this case they didn't make any visible difference.   The third is because [`-O3` often makes your program *slower* than `-O2` would have](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11546075/is-optimisation-level-o3-dangerous-in-g/19985801#19985801).

Answer (score 1):

The `-framework` option is specific to Apple platforms, as the Cocoa, IOKit and CoreVideo frameworks themselves. The build commands and options you are using are for macOS it would appear.